# How to avoid vue component redraw?

Tags: vuejs2

I have prepared tag input control in Vue with tag grouping. Templates includes:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="tem_vtags">
<div class="v-tags">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in model.items" :key="index" :data-group="getGroupName(item)"><div :data-value="item"><span v-if="typeof model.tagRenderer != 'function'">{{ item }}</span><span v-if="typeof model.tagRenderer == 'function'" v-html="tagRender(item)"></span></div><div data-remove="" @click="remove(index)">x</div></li>
  </ul>
  <textarea v-model="input" placeholder="type value and hit enter" @keydown="inputKeydown($event,input)"></textarea>
  <button v-on:click="add(input)">Apply</button>
</div>
</script>
```

I have defined component method called `.getGroupName()` which relays on other function called `.qualifier()` that can be set over props.

My problem: once I add any tags to collection (`.items`) when i type anything into textarea for each keydown `.getGroupName()` seems to be called. It looks like entering anything to textarea results all component rerender?

**Do you know how to avoid this behavior?** I expect `.getGroupName` to be called only when new tag is added.

Heres the full code:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKOJjo?editors=1011 (i have placed `debugger;` to catch when runtime enters `.qualifier()`.

Any help appriciated.

It Man

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR;**
You can't, what you can do is optimize to reduce function calls.

---

the redraws are dynamic, triggered by data change. because you have functions (`v-model` and `@keydown`) you will update the data. The issue is that when you call a function: `:data-group="getGroupName(item)"` it will execute every time, because it makes no assumptions on what data may have changed.

One way of dealing with is is setting groupName as a computed key-val object that you can look up without calling the function. Then you can use `:data-group="getGroupName[item]"` without calling the function on redraw. The same should be done for  `v-html="tagRender(item)"`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to fight how the framework handles data input events and rendering, instead use it to your advantage:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#example',
  data() {
    return {
      someInput: '',
      someInputStore: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      if (this.someInputStore.indexOf(this.someInput) === -1) {
        this.someInputStore.push(this.someInput);
        this.someInput = '';
      }
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <template id="example">
    <div>
      <textarea v-model="someInput" @keyup.enter.exact="add" @keyup.shift.enter=""></textarea>
      <button @click="add">click to add new input</button>
      <div>
        {{ someInputStore }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

### Event modifiers modifying

In the example, you can see that I am using 4 different event modifiers in order to achieve the desired outcome, but I will focus on the combination of them here:

1. **`@keyup.enter.exact`** - allows control of the exact combination of system modifiers needed to trigger an event. In this case, we are looking for the enter button.
2. **`@keyup.shift.enter`** - this is the interesting bit. Instead of trying to hackily *prevent* the framework from firing on both events, we can use this (and a blank value) to prevent the event we added into `@keyup.enter.exact` from firing. I must note that `=""` is critical to the whole setup working properly. Without it, you aren't giving vue an alternative to firing the `add` method, as shown by my example.

***I hope this helps!***